# 301 redirect via .htaccess dont redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having trouble with this redirect and maybe someone of you can help me.

I need to redirect this:

```
/modules.php?name=challenge_us
```

to this:

```
/modules.php?name=Clan_Manager&action=recruitment_apply&fid=3
```

I tried appending to the .htaccess file this with no luck:

```
Redirect 301 /modules.php?name=challenge_us /modules.php?name=Clan_Manager&action=recruitment_apply&fid=3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this into your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=challenge_us [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /modules.php?name=Clan_Manager&action=recruitment_apply&fid=3 [R=301,L]
```